# how to call smart contract function in C#.net core

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens, nethereum, c#

```
protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var senderAddress = "0x605a1f8d368cbdd4d0a5cbad74f75c428660f17b";
            var password = "zxcasdqwe123";
            var abi = @"[{""constant"":false,""inputs"":[{""name"":""passAddress"",""type"":""address""}],""name"":""isWhitelisted"",""outputs"":[{""name"":"""",""type"":""bool""}],""payable"":false,""type"":""function""},{""constant"":false,""inputs"":[{""name"":""userAddress"",""type"":""address""}],""name"":""userAdd"",""outputs"":[],""payable"":false,""type"":""function""},{""inputs"":[],""payable"":false,""type"":""constructor""}]";
            var web3 = new Nethereum.Web3.Web3();
            var newAddress = "0xE96932536293CF4712180973c6201DDbDf6fa3C0";
            /*var unlockAccountResult = await web3.Personal.UnlockAccount.SendRequestAsync(senderAddress, password, new HexBigInteger(120));
            Assert.True(unlockAccountResult);
            */
            //var transactionHash = await web3.Eth.DeployContract.SendRequestAsync(abi, byteCode, senderAddress, newAddress);
            //var receipt = await web3.Eth.Transactions.GetTransactionReceipt.SendRequestAsync(transactionHash);
            //while (receipt == null)
            //{
            //    Thread.Sleep(5000);
            //    receipt = await web3.Eth.Transactions.GetTransactionReceipt.SendRequestAsync(transactionHash);
            //}
            //var contractAddress = receipt.ContractAddress;
            var contract = web3.Eth.GetContract(abi, "0x23699275461c4755377c293bb657e84d3ddfdbd9");
            var fucntion = contract.GetFunction("userAdd");
            var result = await fucntion.CallAsync<String>("0xE96932536293CF4712180973c6201DDbDf6fa3C0");
        }
```

I have deployed my contract on rinkeby and got the address and now i am calling my fucntion of my contract but it is showing me null.

help
thanx in advance

Comment: **always mask passwords when you post stuff here!**

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this question? If so, kindly share.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19238)

Answer (score 2):

From your ABI it looks like there are no output parameters for the function `userAdd`?

If you are trying to send a transaction to modify state you should use `function.SendTransactionAsync(...)` not `CallAsync`

There will be no value returned from a transaction. Check the status in the receipt.

Also, depending on the version of Nethereum you are using you may need to Unlock the sending account first.

HTH